# Wordpress dashboard metabox with 'My Recent Pages'

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to create a Wordpress dashboard metabox which lists the 5 most recent pages created by the currently logged in user. Each page would be listed as a link to the individual page. Any help in doing this would be much appreciated.

The code I've created lists posts but not pages.

Here is an example:

```
add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'recent_pages');

function recent_pages() {
global $wp_meta_boxes;

wp_add_dashboard_widget('My Recent Pages', 'My Recent Pages', 'my_recent_pages');
}


function my_recent_pages() {

if ( is_user_logged_in() ):

    global $current_user;
    wp_get_current_user();
    $author_query = array('posts_per_page' => '5,','author' => $current_user->ID);
    $author_pages = new WP_Query($author_query);
    while($author_pages->have_posts()) : $author_pages->the_post();
    ?>
        <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
    <?php
    endwhile;

else :

    echo "not logged in";

endif;


}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? can you edit your question to include some code?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've included the code.